# Websocket onMessage ring the bell only once even there are multiple browser tabs listening for the messages

Tags: websocket

I have a active websocket connection on each tab of the browser.
when there is a message received by each of the tabs, they are all ringing the bells which is annoying.
Is there a way i can ring the bell only once even multiple tabs open(Facebook is doing this)

Answer (score 0):

If you control the server, you can unicast the "ring" event to a specific connection (I would suggest the latest connection) while broadcasting, as you do now, the actual message to all the websocket connections.

If you don't control the server, I doubt there is an easily applicable solution.